# date is always one less than required date

Tags: javascript, datetime, datepicker

i have a javascript date object like

```
Mon Jun 20 2016 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)
```

And i have using the following code to get `yy-mm-dd` format

```
    var month = $scope.dt.getUTCMonth() + 1; //months from 1-12
    var day = $scope.dt.getUTCDate();
    var year = $scope.dt.getUTCFullYear();
    $scope.date_in_format=year + "-" + month + "-" + day;
```

But date variable day is always 1 less the actual date.In this case day=19.How to solve it?When i modify as

```
var day = $scope.dt.getUTCDate()+1;
```

It wont work when actual date is 1 day variable become 31+1=32

Comment: I think, you don’t want to use `UTC` then.

Answer (score 2):

It is because `getUTCDate` will subtract 5 hours 30 minutes from `Jun 20 2016 00:00:00` and you get the previous day. Try `getDate()` instead.

See the difference here:

```js
function myFunction() {
    var d = new Date(2016, 06, 20, 0, 0, 0);
    var n1 = d.getDate();
    var n2 = d.getUTCDate();
    document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = n1;
    document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = n2;

}
```

```html
<p>Click the button to display the day of the month, according to UTC.</p>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Try it</button>

<p id="demo1"></p>

<p id="demo2"></p>
```